# How to find highest value in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `x` with this values:

```
   x1  x2  x3
1  NA   4   1
2  NA   3  NA
3   4  NA   2
4  NA   1  11
5  NA   2  NA
6   5  NA   1
7   5   9  NA
8  NA   2  NA
```

A simple question: **How do I get the highest value?** (11)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `max()` with the `na.rm` argument set to `TRUE`:

```
dat <- read.table(text="
   x1  x2  x3
1  NA   4   1
2  NA   3  NA
3   4  NA   2
4  NA   1  11
5  NA   2  NA
6   5  NA   1
7   5   9  NA
8  NA   2  NA", header=TRUE)
```

Get the maximum:

```
max(dat, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 11
```

Answer (score 2):

To find the sum of a column, you might want to unlist it first;

```
max(unlist(myDataFrame$myColumn), na.rm = TRUE)
```

[Source](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/max-number-from-a-list-of-numbers-td2225172.html)

Answer (score 1):

you could write a column maximum function, `colMax`.

```
colMax <- function(data) sapply(data, max, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Use colMax function on sample data:

```
colMax(x)
#    x1     x2     x3
#   5.0    9.0    11.0
```